# Passing grid view row to a method in another class library

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a grid view in my Winforms project and I want to pass each row of the grid to a `methodX()` in another class library project.

My question is what would be the data type of the row to pass to `methodX()` ?

I tried to pass it like this from my Winforms project:

```
obj.methodX(gridview.Rows[i]);
```

In class library project, methodx is defined like this:

```
public void methodX(string[] gridviewRowData)
{

}
```

Can you please suggest me that right data type I would use in here.

Comment: It looks like methodX takes a string[] parameter, so you need to convert your gridview.Rows[i] to a string array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing `gridview.Rows[i]`, the method signature you are looking for is:

```
public void methodX(DataGridView dataGridView) {

}
```

That means you are passing the `DataGridView` row at index `i` to the method

Comment: Doesn't look right.  When you pass gridview.Rows[i] you are actually passing an individual DataGridViewRow object, not an entire DataGridView object, as Adrian Carneiro has suggested.

Comment: I am using a separate C# library and have tried to pass in DataGridView into a method but it returns a The type or namespace 'DataGridView' could not be found. Unfortunately, the project does not give me the option of using a using statement with system.ui.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridViewRowCollection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).
Its a collection that handles the rows in a datagridview.

And after that you can access each cell information by rows["columnName"].value;
Here is a short example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the rows from the datagridview
        DataGridViewRowCollection rows = new DataGridViewRowCollection(dataGridView1);

        //and now call your method
        GetRowsInfo(rows);

    }

    //method that takes an argument of DataGridViewRowCollection type, iterates through all the rows and displays every cell content(generically speaking).
    public void GetRowsInfo(DataGridViewRowCollection dataRows)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in dataRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row["columnName"] + row["columnName"] + "...");


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a single row, which is what you are doing with this line:

```
obj.methodX(gridview.Rows[i]);
```

Then your methodX needs to look like this:

```
public void methodX(DataGridViewRow row)
{

}
```

Alternatively, use the DataGridViewRowCollection, as suggested by @lauCosma

Or you can also just pass the entire DataGridView into methodX and then loop through each row inside of methodX:

```
obj.methodX(gridview);

public void methodX(DataGridView gridview)
{    
    foreach DataGridViewRow row in gridview.Rows)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Or you can also use DataGridView.SelectedRows property to pass just the highlighted/selected rows collection to methodX.